# Why in max-cut ( weigthted graph )we can't do an approximation lower than 1/2?

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, np, turing-machines

I have been trying to solve the Max-Cut problem using  approximation algorithms, but I still don't get how the best approximation I can get is 1/2. I could use any help or paper of proof of this fact.

Comment: Wikipedia tells me it's actually possible to get a 0.878-approximation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut#Approximation_algorithms

Comment: In the future, I advise you to consider [the computer science stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com) instead of stackoverflow for these types of theoretical questions. You might be more likely to get enlightening answers over there.

Comment: thanks you both, i didnt know that there is another forum.